# How to scrape story_id from facebook mbasic version?

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The mbasic facebook lxml file looks like:

```
<div class="feed" id="structured_composer_async_container"><section class="_7k7 storyStream _5nxi"> 
<article class="_55wo _56bf _5rgl" data-ft=" {&quot;**mf_story_id:4364550910283823**&quot;,&quot;top_level_post_id&quot;:&quot;4364550910283823&quot;,&quot;tl_objid&quot;:&quot;4364550910283823&quot;,&quot;content_owner_id_new&quot;:&quot;100001868724006&quot;,&quot;original_content_id&quot;:&quot;716340598960028&quot;,&quot;original_content_owner_i0</span></a></div></div>...
```

And, I want to scrape the "mf_story_id" of each of the post from a facebook page,
I used this particular code using Beautiful-Soup and Request:

```
post_id=[]
    for element in soup.find_all("section"):
        for article in element.find_all("article"):
            for xyz in article.find_all("data-ft"):
                post_id.append(xyz["mf_story_id"])
            
post_id = ' '.join(post_id)     
return post_id
```

But it's giving me null value, How shall I modify the code in order to scrape the required data?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example to parse the Json inside `data-ft=` attribute:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
<div class="feed" id="structured_composer_async_container">
<section class="_7k7 storyStream _5nxi"> 
<article class="_55wo _56bf _5rgl" data-ft="{&quot;mf_story_id&quot;:&quot;4364550910283823&quot;,&quot;top_level_post_id&quot;:&quot;4364550910283823&quot;}">
</section>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for article in soup.select('article[data-ft]'):
    data_ft = json.loads(article['data-ft'])
    print(data_ft['mf_story_id'])
```

Prints:

```
4364550910283823
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from ast import literal_eval


txt = '''
<div class="feed" id="structured_composer_async_container">
<section class="_7k7 storyStream _5nxi"> 
<article class="_55wo _56bf _5rgl" data-ft="{&quot;mf_story_id&quot;:&quot;4364550910283823&quot;,&quot;top_level_post_id&quot;:&quot;4364550910283823&quot;}">
</section>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

target = literal_eval(soup.select_one("article._55wo._56bf._5rgl")['data-ft'])

print(target)
print(target.keys())
```

Output:

```
{'mf_story_id': '4364550910283823', 'top_level_post_id': '4364550910283823'}
dict_keys(['mf_story_id', 'top_level_post_id'])
```